# Xamarin: Error while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException for EntityFramework

Tags: android, mysql, entity-framework, xamarin

I know that there are several questions and answers for similar issues but unfortunately none of them could solve my problem.
So as I started to add a DatabaseConnection (adding the standard MySQL references and writing an DatabaseConnection Class) I got this error when trying to build:

---

*"Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'EntityFramework.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   Mobile Diagnosis    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets 1500"*

---

I already tried to add some packages via NuGet, tried to rebuild, clean, build again, restart Visual Studio and also tried to find the missing .dll. I didn't. So now the question: What should I do? What did I do wrong? Do I need to add this .dll manually or is there something else wrong?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: do you get answer for this